# Use Selenium to test for print window in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to verify that clicking a print button opens the print dialog. The button calls javaScript that calls window.print().
I get an exception, but the print view opens.  I am unable to select the print view. I can inspect the with the dev tools and it is showing HTML.

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   .../session/888062777289e469e06bab59a6ea6c29/element/0.4957923940382898-7/click
>   timed out after 60 seconds.

driver.FindElement(By.Id("print-preview")); does not find the window.
The dev tools say the address is chrome://print/, but it looks like an overlay.

Is there a way to interact with the print dialog? I'm only going to run the test on Chrome.

I'm also open to using MS Coded UI and am going to start looking into that.

Comment: You might be able to use `switchTo().window()`, if it's truly HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I wasn't able to get that to work.